# SQL Server - Get Values based on ID where another column doesnt have all values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

This might be an easy one, but i'm not too familiar with sql server and advanced usages. Basically I am unable to form a query for this.

I have a table which looks like below. Each ID has a type which has only 3 values (0,1,2).

```
ID      Type
40271   0
40271   1
40271   2
40281   0
40281   1
```

I want to select only the IDs which DO NOT have  all the Types.

**Output(Since its missing the 3rd type i.e 2):**

```
    ID      Type
    40281   0
    40281   1
```

I need to select all rows from table where for each ID, all types(0,1,2) do not exist.

I tried group by, having etc clauses but couldnt quite reach there.

I tried this, but it gives me both the IDs

```
select ID 
    from Table
    group by ID
    having count(distinct Type) > 1
```

Comment: you want `having count(distinct type) < 3` and you should probably have that as an in/exists statement. e.g. `select id, type from mytable t where exists (select 1 from mytable where id = t.id group by id having count(distinct type) < 3)`

Comment: @ZLK That was it. Just needed `having count(distinct type) < 3`. I knew i'm close, just couldn't think right. Thank you sir! Add it as an answer and I shall accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is using `EXISTS` to check whether the ID has less than three types.

```
SELECT ID, Type
FROM Table T
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table
    WHERE ID = T.ID
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Type) < 3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select t.* from test1 t, 
  (select id, count(*) cnt from test1 group by id) t1
where t.id = t1.id
   and t1.cnt < 3
```

Comment: Joining in a `where` statement is deprecated. Please use `inner join`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122(v=vs.100).aspx